# Are Font Identification questions on-topic?

Tags: support, on-topic, off-topic

A client uses a certain font in their logo, and I need to be able to use this font in other places. Unfortunately, no one I can speak with knows what the font is. Are "font identification" questions on-topic? Wherein I would post the logo and hope someone can sleuth it out/recognizes it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be something more for the graphic design site than the UX site.  You could also try using something like FontBook to narrow down the font characteristics and then browse through whichever fonts are left until you find the right one.